# what is the voltage direction and current direction of LVDS signal at particular time?

Tags: lvds

What is the voltage and current direction LVDS signal (how it is related) ? 
i.e at a time (t1) there is only one current direction and one voltage ( D+ or D-)

Answer (score 2):

First, read about how LVDS works. https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-5017.pdf

The two outputs D+ and D- have nominal voltage levels of 1.4 volts and 1.07 volts for a logic 1, and 1.07 volts and 1.40 volts for a logic 0.

So the answer is no. Each output can have one of two different voltages, and current can flow in either direction.

Comment: Rt(LVDS termination drop) drop is 350mV. So it means,
350mV will be reduced from D- ?

Comment: 350mV drop will be affected in D- voltage ?

Comment: 350 mV is the standard number for a termination of 100 ohms. If 2 terminating resistors are used, the voltage across the resistors will be somewhat less. And whether the voltage changes D- (it does) or D+ (it does) or both of them (it does) is unimportant. The receiver is _differential_ (that's the D in LVDS) and within limits (common mode range) all that matters is the difference in voltage across the resistor.

Comment: OK noted. 

1) Who is generating D+ and D- ? 
2) How many current flowing through the circuit at a time (t1) ?
3) There are two signals, one is D+ and another is D-. So there will be two current at a time flowing through the resistor ?
4) The return path of one current is driven by whom D+ or D- signal?

Comment: Please read the link.

Comment: Hello, Link is not attached here. Can you share the link once again ?

Comment: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-5017.pdf  If that didn't work, search for Fairchild LVDS Application Note 5017.

Comment: I could enter https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-5017.pdf